# Failed to resolve RestSharp.RestClient dotnetStandard2.0 project with Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, nuget-package, restsharp, .net-standard-2.0

There are 2 projects in my solution. Xamarin iOS native and dotnetstandard 2.0. I need to use RestSharp in dotnetstandard 2.0 project. But when I create variable `RestClient client;` it causes an error. [image]
Pcl code is following:

[image]

When I remove this variable my project builds successfully. I have also tried to use RestSharp.Portable but faced another issues. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this also adding Restsharp nuget to ios project from which I called restsharp method in the .netstandard 2.0. So you need Restsharp nugets in both projects.

Comment: This is what worked for me too. The iOS simulator built for me and the physical device didn't. It was really weird.

Comment: I use only physical device